# how to add filters to my adf table with array list object java?

Tags: java, filter, oracle-adf, jspx

i am new to jdeveloper working with adf projects.

I have a table loaded by a java arraylist that gets data from a rest service.

this is my model

```
public class model {

    String campo1, campo2, campo3;
  //construct - Getter and Setter
}
```

this is my controller

```
public class controller {
    model d = new model();
    List<model> lts_person = new ArrayList();
    RichTable table;
    FilterableQueryDescriptor decriptor;
//construct - Getter and Setter
}
```

this is my jspx -> af:table

```
        <af:table summary="demo" var="row" rowBandingInterval="1" id="t1"
                  inlineStyle="width:60.0%;" value="#{lista.lts_person}"
                  rowSelection="single" varStatus="vs"
                  filterModel="#{lista.table}" filterVisible="true"
                  emptyText="Data Not Found">
          <af:column sortable="true" headerText="Codigo" id="c1"
                     filterable="true" sortProperty="campo1">
            <af:outputText value="#{row.campo1}" id="ot1"/>
          </af:column>
          <af:column sortable="true" headerText="Nombres" id="c3"
                     filterable="true" sortProperty="campo2">
            <af:outputText value="#{row.campo2}" id="ot2"/>
          </af:column>
          <af:column sortable="true" headerText="Apellidos" id="c2"
                     filterable="true" sortProperty="campo3">
            <af:outputText value="#{row.campo3}" id="ot3"/>
          </af:column>
        </af:table>
```

I have seen that I have to convert from my model to Richtable and then pass it through FilterableQueryDescriptor and return a Descriptor but I don't understand how to do it.

In the af: table I understand that the Descriptor in the filter model and the Binding do not know if necessary.